# Installing Mahout on Amazon EC2 instance - get_reference_source command not found

Tags: amazon-ec2

As my school project, I've created a AWS EC2 instance and trying to install different "Dev Tools" and software as per AWS doc [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html.
][1]

I'm trying to get mahout tarball using get_reference_source -p mahout while connecting to AWS instance via putty. 
But this command gives error "get_reference_source " command not found. I'm searching for it since morning and found nothing.

Comment: Nothing to do with mahout; it's all that this get_reference_source tool is missing.

Comment: Ya, it would be great if I get some help on how to get that tool.. I'm searching all over onto that AWS docs..